# Final Fantasy VI Timed out, crashes on start

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-5, bugs

I get the following errors when trying to start Final Fantasy VI on my Galaxy S5. Running stock rooted rom. I have cleared the cache, I have uninstalled/cleaned all traces from my phone, then installed again, I have flashed other roms. I have not tried on another device, as I do not have access to another S5. My Note 2 runs it without issue. Logcat for this package is located below. I have tested by disabling samsung smart face as you see it does have its onReceive in the middle (trying to eliminate variables.)

Thank you in advance!

[image: Logcat]

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post an answer so that other users can see. Don't edit solutions into the question.

Comment: You cannot answer your own question for 8 hours. I added the edit until that timeframe had passed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few things that helped. I was able to get it to work by flashing stock with oden, reflashing my rom, then downloading the game. I was able to reproduce the issue when I backed up FF VI via titanium backup then recovered it. This seemed to cause this issue until the system was cleared. I will do some more testing to see what in the system needed to be cleared before it would work.